# Error while passing argument

Tags: c#

I have a UserBll class which has  following method

```
public string GetaspnetUserIdByUserName(string name )
{
    string _lsttUserId = (from aspnet in db.aspnet_Users
                            where aspnet.UserName.Equals(name)
                            select aspnet.UserId
                         ).ToString();
    return _lsttUserId;
}
```

I create an instance of Usertable having UserId and UserName field and I am using following code

```
UserBLL bll = new UserBL
UserTable uTable = new UserTable();
uTable.UserId = bll.GetaspnetUserIdByUserName(Membership.GetUser(model.UserName));
```

in above code I get following error:

> GetaspnetUserIdByUserName has some invalid argument

Can somebody please tell me what wrong I am doing

Comment: Try cleaning up the question's formatting. Most people will not read this being such a mess.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: the exact error is best overloaded method match for GetaspnetUserIdByUserName has some invalid argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Membership.GetUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx) does not return a string, it returns a [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx).

You want:

```
string username = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName).UserName;
```

In case you want to see whats going on:

```
MembershipUser theUser = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
string userName = theUser.UserName;
```

Comment: you are passing `UserName` to get `UserId` when its already there as `ProviderUserKey` in the `MembershipUser`. What is the point of the BLL function. Am i missing anything?

Comment: I dont understand your question?  It *looks* like he is trying to lookup a user id from a string?

Comment: please look down at my answer. i am asking this because the tables he refer to have a foreign key relationship in userid and he is seeking that.

Comment: @naveen yes I know that but when I use that approach I can't access providerkey

Comment: interesting.. is this your own custom provider or asp.net membership provider.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to be calling the function like this:

```
UserBLL bll = new UserBL
UserTable uTable = new UserTable();
uTable.UserId = bll.GetaspnetUserIdByUserName(model.UserName);
```

Assuming that `model.UserName` is a `string` value.

Answer (score 1):

The BLL function is needless.

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("{your desired user name}");
UserTable uTable = new UserTable();
uTable.UserId = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

Because `MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey` == `aspnet_User.UserId`

Comment: yeah I did that but when I do that I get error that can't convert integer to string